# Red Circle Around Custom Android Button Image

Tags: android, xml, image, android-layout, android-studio

I have created a floating action button, and made my own image (at each of dpi sizes), but there is a red circle around it (image below).  Here is my xml defining the button

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
android:id="@+id/addplant"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
android:src="@mipmap/add_plant"/>
```

Here is my source image (@192x192), and a screenshot of what i'm seeing in android studio.
[image: My Plus Sign]

[image: red border around image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT 2**

No need to use `app:backgroundTint` juse USE **`android:scaleType="center"`** in your `FloatingActionButton` it will work

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/addplant"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:scaleType="center"
    android:src="@mipmap/add_plant" />
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Try this

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/addplant"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@drawable/add_plant"/>
```

> android:src="@drawable/add_plant"

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:width="24dp"
        android:height="24dp"
        android:viewportWidth="24.0"
        android:viewportHeight="24.0">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:pathData="M19,13h-6v6h-2v-6H5v-2h6V5h2v6h6v2z"/>
</vector>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

**EDIT**

To support **`vector`** drawablea add this in  your **`build.gradle`** file

```
defaultConfig {
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
 }
```

Comment: you're suggesting to use the vector graphic as opposed to the drawable?

Comment: Thanks, you're second edit fixed it.  Looks great! :)

Answer (score 4):

You can try the below -

```
   <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    ...
    ...
    android:src="@drawable/icon" // change backgroung icon
    app:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent" // change background color
    />
```

setting tint to transparent will override that primary color pink you have given in styles.

Answer (score 2):

Try using XML attribute **app:backgroundTint**

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/addplant"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/orange" // -----> your background color
        android:src="@mipmap/add_plant" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this

> app:useCompatPadding="true"

Comment: This didn't work, it just expanded the border of the button.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the **+** symbol alone as source. You need not pass the whole image with green background. To set the green background color use `app:backgroundTint="@color/green"`

Change your code like this and use green color for backgroundTint and plus icon as source:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/green"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_plus" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use background color

> app:backgroundTint="@color/green"

remove background color from image, use image without background https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/10/10/01/49/plus-1727487__340.png

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/addplant"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/green"
    android:src="@mipmap/add_plant"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because Floating action button is colored by the colorAccent attribute in your [theme](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/floating-action-button). you can set the background tint to green. I have updated your code.

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
android:id="@+id/addplant"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
android:backgroundTint="#4CAF50"
android:src="@mipmap/add_plant"/>
```